# What is this connector called that looks like a small mono audio jack?

Tags: connector, identification

The thermocouple from my oven thermometer has a connector that looks somewhat like a mono audio jack, but smaller:

[image]

The connector is around 2.4 mm thick in the long, extended section and around 11.2 mm long.

Does someone know what this is called? Or is it proprietary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It Looks like a standard 2.5 mm audio jack plug.